# 2 different action in one form

Tags: php, forms, action

I have a form called addcustomer.php . it's contain firsname, lastname, mobile fields.i have also 2 button on this form. onr button for saving data and the others for sending sms to customers.
i want to when i click second button 3 data fields passed to another form called smsinfo.php.
now action for saving data works good but when direct to smsinfo . there is no data on this form .

```
<form method ="POST" name = "custform" action="">
<div class="cell_2_2"><label class="lblfields">Firstname:</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="firstname" autocomplete="off"/></div>
<div class="cell_3_2"><label class="lblfields">Lastname :</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="lastname" autocomplete="off"/></div>    
<div class="cell_5_2"><label class="lblfields">Mobile :</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="mobile" autocomplete="off"/></div>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/>
 <input type="submit" name="sendsms" value="Sms"/>

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
Saving code here

} else if (isset($_POST['sendsms'])) {
header("Location: smsinfo.php");
}
```

here code of smsinfo.php:

```
<?php
$Fname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
$Lname = $_REQUEST['lastname'];
$Mob = $_REQUEST['mobile'];
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="sendingsms.php" method="POST">
<input style="width: 100px;" name="firstname"  type="text" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>"/>
 <input style="width: 100px;" name="lastname"  type="text" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>"/>
 <input style="width: 100px;" name="mobile"  type="text" value="<?php echo $mobile; ?>"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks all and sorry for my poor english

Comment: header("Location: smsinfo.php"); does not send data

Why not just put the sms code inside the else clause of if (isset($_POST['submit']))?

Comment: If you must redirect using header("Location: smsinfo.php"), you can attach the form data to URL inside the header("Location: smsinfo.php").

Comment: How can i reach to smsinfo.php instead of using header ?

Comment: Did you tried $_POST['firstname']

Comment: Yes ,but  no effect

Comment: As Mossa Khalil said "header("Location: smsinfo.php"); does not send data".i think problem is here .